# What shall be changed about stm32f4x7_eth_bsp.c

Tags: ethernet, gcc, freertos, stm32f4

I am using STM32f407ZGT6. FreeRTOS is running perfectly on Board! I have included Ethernet files. According compilation of Windows Commander stating that it was compiled lacked free. But if one connects with LAN on this board, the connection does not work!(Ethernet LED is working ) I assume that it was not initialized properly in the file name stm32f4x7_eth_bsp.c. ( For example Initialization of GPIO PIN, nvic, etc ) I have written some changes initialization. But still the connection of the Ethernet did not work! I still might forget to initialize properly in this file. Please I need your help!

Here is the Code of stm32f4x7_eth_bsp.c

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    stm32f4x7_eth_bsp.c
  * @author  MCD Application Team
  * @version V1.1.0
  * @date    31-July-2013 
  * @brief   STM32F4x7 Ethernet hardware configuration.
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT 2013 STMicroelectronics</center></h2>
  *
  * Licensed under MCD-ST Liberty SW License Agreement V2, (the "License");
  * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  * You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *
  *        http://www.st.com/software_license_agreement_liberty_v2
  *
  * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
  * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
  * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  * limitations under the License.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "lwip/opt.h"
#include "stm32f4x7_eth.h"
#include "stm32f4x7_eth_bsp.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "netif.h"
#include "netconf.h"
#include "lwip/dhcp.h"

/* Scheduler includes */
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "semphr.h"

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* The time to block waiting for input. */
#define ETH_LINK_TASK_STACK_SIZE        ( configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE * 2 )
#define ETH_LINK_TASK_PRIORITY              ( tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 3 )
#define emacBLOCK_TIME_WAITING_ETH_LINK_IT  ( ( portTickType ) 100 )
/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ETH_InitTypeDef ETH_InitStructure;
__IO uint32_t  EthStatus = 0;
extern struct netif xnetif;
#ifdef USE_DHCP
extern __IO uint8_t DHCP_state;
#endif /* LWIP_DHCP */
xSemaphoreHandle ETH_link_xSemaphore = NULL;

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
static void ETH_GPIO_Config(void);
static void ETH_NVIC_Config(void);
static void ETH_MACDMA_Config(void);

/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
  * @brief  ETH_BSP_Config
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void ETH_BSP_Config(void)
{
  /* Configure the GPIO ports for ethernet pins */
  ETH_GPIO_Config();

  /* Config NVIC for Ethernet */
  ETH_NVIC_Config();

  /* Configure the Ethernet MAC/DMA */
  ETH_MACDMA_Config();

  /* Get Ethernet link status*/
  if(ETH_ReadPHYRegister(DP83848_PHY_ADDRESS, PHY_SR) & 1)
  {
    EthStatus |= ETH_LINK_FLAG;
  }

  /* Configure the PHY to generate an interrupt on change of link status */
  Eth_Link_PHYITConfig(DP83848_PHY_ADDRESS);

  /* Configure the EXTI for Ethernet link status. */
  Eth_Link_EXTIConfig();

  if (ETH_link_xSemaphore == NULL)
  {
    /* create binary semaphore used for ETH_link handling */
    vSemaphoreCreateBinary( ETH_link_xSemaphore );
  }

  /* create the task that handles the ETH_link */
  xTaskCreate(Eth_Link_IT_task, (signed char*) "E_link", ETH_LINK_TASK_STACK_SIZE, (void *)DP83848_PHY_ADDRESS,
              ETH_LINK_TASK_PRIORITY,NULL);
}

/**
  * @brief  Configures the Ethernet Interface
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
static void ETH_MACDMA_Config(void)
{ 
  /* Enable ETHERNET clock  */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_ETH_MAC | RCC_AHB1Periph_ETH_MAC_Tx |
                         RCC_AHB1Periph_ETH_MAC_Rx | RCC_AHB1Periph_ETH_MAC_PTP, ENABLE);

  /* Reset ETHERNET on AHB Bus */
  ETH_DeInit();

  /* Software reset */
  ETH_SoftwareReset();

  /* Wait for software reset */
  while (ETH_GetSoftwareResetStatus() == SET);

  /* ETHERNET Configuration --------------------------------------------------*/
  /* Call ETH_StructInit if you don't like to configure all ETH_InitStructure parameter */
  ETH_StructInit(&ETH_InitStructure);

  /* Fill ETH_InitStructure parametrs */
  /*------------------------   MAC   -----------------------------------*/
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_AutoNegotiation = ETH_AutoNegotiation_Disable;     
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_LoopbackMode = ETH_LoopbackMode_Disable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_RetryTransmission = ETH_RetryTransmission_Disable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_AutomaticPadCRCStrip = ETH_AutomaticPadCRCStrip_Disable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_ReceiveAll = ETH_ReceiveAll_Enable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_BroadcastFramesReception = ETH_BroadcastFramesReception_Disable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_PromiscuousMode = ETH_PromiscuousMode_Disable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_MulticastFramesFilter = ETH_MulticastFramesFilter_Perfect;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_UnicastFramesFilter = ETH_UnicastFramesFilter_Perfect;
    ETH_InitStructure.ETH_Mode = ETH_Mode_FullDuplex;                        
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_Speed = ETH_Speed_100M;

#ifdef CHECKSUM_BY_HARDWARE
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_ChecksumOffload = ETH_ChecksumOffload_Enable;
#endif

  /*------------------------   DMA   -----------------------------------*/  

  /* When we use the Checksum offload feature, we need to enable the Store and Forward mode: 
  the store and forward guarantee that a whole frame is stored in the FIFO, so the MAC can insert/verify the checksum, 
  if the checksum is OK the DMA can handle the frame otherwise the frame is dropped */
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_DropTCPIPChecksumErrorFrame = ETH_DropTCPIPChecksumErrorFrame_Enable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_ReceiveStoreForward = ETH_ReceiveStoreForward_Enable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_TransmitStoreForward = ETH_TransmitStoreForward_Enable;

  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_ForwardErrorFrames = ETH_ForwardErrorFrames_Disable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_ForwardUndersizedGoodFrames = ETH_ForwardUndersizedGoodFrames_Disable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_SecondFrameOperate = ETH_SecondFrameOperate_Enable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_AddressAlignedBeats = ETH_AddressAlignedBeats_Enable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_FixedBurst = ETH_FixedBurst_Enable;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_RxDMABurstLength = ETH_RxDMABurstLength_32Beat;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_TxDMABurstLength = ETH_TxDMABurstLength_32Beat;
  ETH_InitStructure.ETH_DMAArbitration = ETH_DMAArbitration_RoundRobin_RxTx_2_1;

  /* Configure Ethernet */
  EthStatus = ETH_Init(&ETH_InitStructure, DP83848_PHY_ADDRESS);

  /* Enable the Ethernet Rx Interrupt */
  ETH_DMAITConfig(ETH_DMA_IT_NIS | ETH_DMA_IT_R, ENABLE);
}

/**
  * @brief  Configures the different GPIO ports.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void ETH_GPIO_Config(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

  /* Enable GPIOs clocks */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA | RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB |
                         RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC | RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOG , ENABLE);

  /* Enable SYSCFG clock */
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG, ENABLE);

  SYSCFG_ETH_MediaInterfaceConfig(SYSCFG_ETH_MediaInterface_RMII);

  /* Configure PA1, PA2, PA3 and PA7*/
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3 | GPIO_Pin_7;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Connect PA1, PA2, PA3 and PA7 to ethernet module*/
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource1, GPIO_AF_ETH);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource2, GPIO_AF_ETH);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource3, GPIO_AF_ETH);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_ETH);

    /* PB
    ETH_RMII_TX_EN: PG11
  */

  /* Configure PG11*/
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_11;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Connect PG11 to ethernet module*/
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_ETH);

  /* Configure PC1, PC4 and PC5*/
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_4 | GPIO_Pin_5;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Connect PC1, PC4 and PC5 to ethernet module*/
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource1, GPIO_AF_ETH);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource4, GPIO_AF_ETH);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource5, GPIO_AF_ETH);

/* PG
    ETH_RMII_TXD0: PG13
    ETH_RMII_TXD1: PG14
  */

  /* Configure PG13 and PG14*/
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Connect PG13 and PG14 to ethernet module*/
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource13, GPIO_AF_ETH);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource14, GPIO_AF_ETH);

  unsigned int PhyAddr;
    union {
      uint32_t    HI_LO;
      struct
      {
        uint16_t  LO;
        uint16_t  HI;
      };
    } PHYID;
  for(PhyAddr = 0; 32 > PhyAddr; PhyAddr++)
  { 
    PHYID.HI = ETH_ReadPHYRegister(PhyAddr,2);
    PHYID.LO = ETH_ReadPHYRegister(PhyAddr,3) & 0xFFF0;
    if((0x00061c50 == PHYID.HI_LO) || (0x02038460 == PHYID.HI_LO)) break;
  }

    if(32 < PhyAddr)
  {
    printf("Ethernet Phy Not Found\n\r");
  }

  /* Configure Ethernet */
  if(0 == ETH_Init(&ETH_InitStructure, PhyAddr))
  {
    printf("Ethernet Initialization Failed\n\r");
  }
  printf("Press Space for exit\n\r");
  printf("Check LAN LEDs\n\r");
}

/**
  * @brief  Configures and enable the Ethernet global interrupt.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void ETH_NVIC_Config(void)
{
  NVIC_InitTypeDef   NVIC_InitStructure; 

  TIM_DeInit(TIM2);

  /* Enable the TIM2 Interrupt */
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM2_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = DISABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
}

/**
  * @brief  Configure the PHY to generate an interrupt on change of link status.
  * @param PhyAddr: external PHY address  
  * @retval None
  */
uint32_t Eth_Link_PHYITConfig(uint16_t PhyAddr)
{
  uint16_t tmpreg = 0;

  /* Read MICR register */
  tmpreg = ETH_ReadPHYRegister(PhyAddr, PHY_MICR);

  /* Enable output interrupt events to signal via the INT pin */
  tmpreg |= (uint32_t)PHY_MICR_INT_EN | PHY_MICR_INT_OE;
  if(!(ETH_WritePHYRegister(PhyAddr, PHY_MICR, tmpreg)))
  {
    /* Return ERROR in case of write timeout */
    return ETH_ERROR;
  }

  /* Read MISR register */
  tmpreg = ETH_ReadPHYRegister(PhyAddr, PHY_MISR);

  /* Enable Interrupt on change of link status */
  tmpreg |= (uint32_t)PHY_MISR_LINK_INT_EN;
  if(!(ETH_WritePHYRegister(PhyAddr, PHY_MISR, tmpreg)))
  {
    /* Return ERROR in case of write timeout */
    return ETH_ERROR;
  }
  /* Return SUCCESS */
  return ETH_SUCCESS;
}

/**
  * @brief  EXTI configuration for Ethernet link status.
  * @param PhyAddr: external PHY address  
  * @retval None
  */
void Eth_Link_EXTIConfig(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
  EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStructure;
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

  /* Enable the INT (PB14) Clock */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(ETH_LINK_GPIO_CLK, ENABLE);
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG, ENABLE);

  /* Configure INT pin as input */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = ETH_LINK_PIN;
  GPIO_Init(ETH_LINK_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Connect EXTI Line to INT Pin */
  SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(ETH_LINK_EXTI_PORT_SOURCE, ETH_LINK_EXTI_PIN_SOURCE);

  /* Configure EXTI line */
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Line = ETH_LINK_EXTI_LINE;
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Falling;
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
  EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStructure);

  /* Enable and set the EXTI interrupt to priority 1*/
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI15_10_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 13;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
}

/**
* @brief  This function handles Ethernet link status.
* @param  None
* @retval None
*/
void Eth_Link_IT_task( void * pvParameters )
{
  uint32_t pcPhyAddr;

  pcPhyAddr = ( uint32_t  ) pvParameters;

  printf("Connect LAN cable and press WKUP button\n\r");

  while (!STM_EVAL_PBGetState (BUTTON_WAKEUP));
  while (STM_EVAL_PBGetState (BUTTON_WAKEUP));
  printf("Please wait...\r");

  for(;;)
  {
    if (xSemaphoreTake( ETH_link_xSemaphore, emacBLOCK_TIME_WAITING_ETH_LINK_IT)==pdTRUE)
    {
      /* Check whether the link interrupt has occurred or not */
      if(((ETH_ReadPHYRegister((uint16_t) pcPhyAddr, PHY_MISR)) & PHY_LINK_STATUS) != 0)
      {
        if((ETH_ReadPHYRegister((uint16_t) pcPhyAddr, PHY_SR) & 1))
        {
            printf("Link up\r\n");
          netif_set_link_up(&xnetif);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Link down\r\n");
          netif_set_link_down(&xnetif);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
/**
  * @brief  Link callback function, this function is called on change of link status.
  * @param  The network interface
  * @retval None
  */
void ETH_link_callback(struct netif *netif)
{
  __IO uint32_t timeout = 0;
 uint32_t tmpreg,RegValue;

  struct ip_addr ipaddr;
  struct ip_addr netmask;
  struct ip_addr gw;
#ifndef USE_DHCP
  uint8_t iptab[4] = {0};
  uint8_t iptxt[20];
#endif /* USE_DHCP */


  if(netif_is_link_up(netif))
  {
    /* Restart the autonegotiation */
    if(ETH_InitStructure.ETH_AutoNegotiation != ETH_AutoNegotiation_Disable)
    {
      /* Reset Timeout counter */
      timeout = 0;

      /* Enable Auto-Negotiation */
      ETH_WritePHYRegister(DP83848_PHY_ADDRESS, PHY_BCR, PHY_AutoNegotiation);

      /* Wait until the auto-negotiation will be completed */
      do
      {
        timeout++;
      } while (!(ETH_ReadPHYRegister(DP83848_PHY_ADDRESS, PHY_BSR) & PHY_AutoNego_Complete) && (timeout < (uint32_t)PHY_READ_TO));

      /* Reset Timeout counter */
      timeout = 0;

      /* Read the result of the auto-negotiation */
      RegValue = ETH_ReadPHYRegister(DP83848_PHY_ADDRESS, PHY_SR);



      /*------------------------ ETHERNET MACCR Re-Configuration --------------------*/
      /* Get the ETHERNET MACCR value */  
      tmpreg = ETH->MACCR;

      /* Set the FES bit according to ETH_Speed value */ 
      /* Set the DM bit according to ETH_Mode value */ 
      tmpreg |= (uint32_t)(ETH_InitStructure.ETH_Speed | ETH_InitStructure.ETH_Mode);

      /* Write to ETHERNET MACCR */
      ETH->MACCR = (uint32_t)tmpreg;

      _eth_delay_(ETH_REG_WRITE_DELAY);
      tmpreg = ETH->MACCR;
      ETH->MACCR = tmpreg;
    }

    /* Restart MAC interface */
    ETH_Start();

#ifdef USE_DHCP
    ipaddr.addr = 0;
    netmask.addr = 0;
    gw.addr = 0;


    DHCP_state = DHCP_START;
#else
    IP4_ADDR(&ipaddr, IP_ADDR0, IP_ADDR1, IP_ADDR2, IP_ADDR3);
    IP4_ADDR(&netmask, NETMASK_ADDR0, NETMASK_ADDR1 , NETMASK_ADDR2, NETMASK_ADDR3);
    IP4_ADDR(&gw, GW_ADDR0, GW_ADDR1, GW_ADDR2, GW_ADDR3);
#endif /* USE_DHCP */

    netif_set_addr(&xnetif, &ipaddr , &netmask, &gw);

    /* When the netif is fully configured this function must be called.*/
    netif_set_up(&xnetif);    

#ifdef USE_LCD
    /* Set the LCD Text Color */
    LCD_SetTextColor(Green);

    /* Display message on the LCD */
    LCD_DisplayStringLine(Line5, (uint8_t*)"  Network Cable is  ");
    LCD_DisplayStringLine(Line6, (uint8_t*)"    now connected   ");

    /* Set the LCD Text Color */
    LCD_SetTextColor(White);

  #ifndef USE_DHCP
    /* Display static IP address */
    iptab[0] = IP_ADDR3;
    iptab[1] = IP_ADDR2;
    iptab[2] = IP_ADDR1;
    iptab[3] = IP_ADDR0;
    sprintf((char*)iptxt, "  %d.%d.%d.%d", iptab[3], iptab[2], iptab[1], iptab[0]); 
    LCD_DisplayStringLine(Line8, (uint8_t*)"  Static IP address   ");
    LCD_DisplayStringLine(Line9, iptxt);

    /* Clear LCD */
    LCD_ClearLine(Line5);
    LCD_ClearLine(Line6);
  #endif /* USE_DHCP */
#endif /* USE_LCD */
  }
  else
  {
    ETH_Stop();
#ifdef USE_DHCP
    DHCP_state = DHCP_LINK_DOWN;
    dhcp_stop(netif);

#endif /* USE_DHCP */

    /*  When the netif link is down this function must be called.*/
    netif_set_down(&xnetif);
#ifdef USE_LCD
    /* Set the LCD Text Color */
    LCD_SetTextColor(Red);

    /* Display message on the LCD */
    LCD_DisplayStringLine(Line5, (uint8_t*)"  Network Cable is  ");
    LCD_DisplayStringLine(Line6, (uint8_t*)"     unplugged   ");

    /* Set the LCD Text Color */
    LCD_SetTextColor(White);
#endif /* USE_LCD */
  }
}

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Mostly important, i don't use LCD. ( Because there is not LCD on this board )!

Many Thanks

Comment: Is this an eval board or your own. If eval, what one? Is your interface MII or RMII? If RMII, do you have a 50Mhz oscillator installed (often not installed on demo boards)? You might try cross-posting at the [STM32 Forum](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/cortex_mx_stm32/AllItems.aspx). There are some good experts there, but little participation by ST.

Comment: Hello Tut, 1st: This is not an eval board. 2nd: Interface is RMII. 3rd 50 MHz oscillator is installed on board.

Comment: How are you using MCO (pin PA8)? Your configuration of that pin appears to be incomplete. You need to add: GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA,8,GPIO_AF_MCO); In my working design using the same processor and PHY, I have the 50Mhz oscillator connected directly to PIN PA1 (RMII_REF_CLK) and the PHY CLKI pin. You might also double-check that your definition for DP83848_PHY_ADDRESS matches the strapping in your design. I'm afraid I'm short on time, but will review some more if I can get a break.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think you can use MCO to clock the PHY when using an RMII interface. The ref manual uses that for MII and shows direct oscillator connection (see my comment above) for RMII.

Comment: Yes, you right, but then i have delete PA8! but it doesn't work again! i have added all my files in in this website, would kindly please look there: http://www.codeforge.com/article/227059

Comment: I am sorry, if i have taken yours time, but this truly my first time working with STM32f407ZGT6 and with FreeRTOS. This is because I am doing internship for one semester.it has taken me for one month to do programming. That I have to do makefile, that will be include with OPENOCD, with SourceCode etc. and it should compiling, debugging and linking only trough windows cmd!

Comment: What hardware do you have for debugging? Is there anything for getting the output from the printf statements? I really don't have the time to wade through all the code and you need to clean it up if you want others to spend time with it. Look at the pins listed in your "Ethernet pins configuration". Not all of those match your configurations, not all are used in an RMII interface, and pins for ports PH and PI do not even exist on your particular processor.

Comment: for debugging is JTAG! And i used MS-DOS Debugger. yes the printf is working very good! FreeRTOS is running on Board, and FreeRTOS-Tasking is working excellent! everything is good only ethernet is the most problem! And the Pin about PH and PI i'm not using it! But about there is interesting answers from you, what did you mean about "not all are used in an RMII interface"? And where shall be config RMII ?

Comment: You should use your debugger and printf statements and include in your question more information than just "the connection does not work". I think you have configured the right pins, but you have not shown a schematic so there is no way to tell. Look at the reference manual (RM0090) under "Reduced media-independent interface: RMII" and it will show the required pins. If you have any doubts about what alternate functions are available on what pins, look at the datasheet Table 7 (Alternate function mapping). Clean up the code, list the right pins, provide debugging information; I'm out of time.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for help, many thanks Tut.

Comment: I have try to look into datasheet Table7. And I have looked in RMII! it is interesting! But there is truly okay! i have found some proble to check with printf, why it doesn't work. ther is one line it happen to stay in endless loop: while (ETH_GetSoftwareResetStatus() == SET);

Comment: this is code:                                       **`FlagStatus ETH_GetSoftwareResetStatus(void)
{
 printf("first pass\r\n");
 
  FlagStatus bitstatus = RESET;
  if((ETH->DMABMR & ETH_DMABMR_SR) != (uint32_t)RESET)
  {
   printf("second pass\r\n");
    bitstatus = SET;
  }
  else
  {
  printf("third pass\r\n");
    bitstatus = RESET;
  }
  printf("fourth pass\r\n");
  return bitstatus;
}`**                                                     it happen to printf: onle the 1st pass, 2nd pass and the 4th pass in endless loop! So something must need to correct about this?

Comment: For anyone having the same problem of an infinite loop, the solution is to move the ethernet clock initialization after the MAC DMA reset. [source](https://community.st.com/thread/3496)